# Gathering ice candidates works but failing to connect

Tags: webrtc, webrtc-android

I have two different WebRTC clients: an Android device and an angular application. I set up a turn and stun server and both seems to work with the [trickle ice tester](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/) and the [webrtc tester](https://test.webrtc.org/).

As you can see here:

[image: trickle ice results]

[image: webrtc test results]

But all ice candidates fail in Firefox when I am watching the candidates in `about:webrtc`.
[image: ice candidates in Firefox]

Does anyone have an explanation for this?
More info:

- A similar error occurs in Google Chrome, but the logs are from Firefox because Firefox has better logging.
- The devices are on different networks, so the host request should fail and the turn server is needed.
- The turn server is a coturn turn server, but I also tried it with a Pion turn server and the same result occurs.
- Firfox logs: https://gist.github.com/Nick-v-L/365b7da10039d28a6a23a27fea15df52
- Coturn logs: https://gist.github.com/Nick-v-L/04c3cfc677847e3cdcb7f6b5ca15c743

Comment: The log is what will help to find the reason. But the log your posted here contains several test runs, which are hard to distinguish. If you could press the "clear log" button, then do only a single test run and post the resulting log again, that could help finding the problem.

Comment: @NilsOhlmeier I updated the firefox log and added the coturn logs for additional info. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simple error in my Android app. When receiving an ice candidate from the signaling server I did the following:

```
peerConnection.AddIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(sdpCandidate, sdpMLineIndex, sdpMid));
```

But as the documentation states you have to create an ice candidate in this order:

```
public IceCandidate(string sdpMid, int sdpMLineIndex, string sdp);
```

So I turned the `sdpCandidate` and `sdpMid` around to fix the issue.

```
peerConnection.AddIceCandidate(new IceCandidate(sdpMid, sdpMLineIndex, sdpCandidate));
```